# Can DAO use an object that itself incapsulates a dataSource object?

Tags: java, design-patterns, jdbc, dao

I have a `DAO`, (call it `PlayerDao`) having the following method:

```
public interface PlayerDao{
    //Other methods
    public Collection<Integer> getPlayerRegisteredIds();
}
```

Now I need to provide two implementation for that method:

***I***. Executing a select query on a dataSource directly like the following:

```
public class PlayerDaoImpl implements PlayerDao{

    private DataSource dataSource; //javax.sql.DataSource
    //Other methods
    public Collection<Integer> getPlayerRegisteredIds(){
        Collection<Integer> result = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String query = "SELECT id FROM player WHERE registered_today = true";
        //Executing the query with the dataSource

        return result;
}
```

***II***. Execute this query by parts. I mean split the query into 4 disjoint parts and execute each part into a separate thread (For improving performance).

```
 public class ConcurrentPlayerDaoImpl implements PlayerDao{
    private static final NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 4;
    private DataSource dataSource; //javax.sql.DataSource
    //Other methods
    public Collection<Integer> getPlayerRegisteredIds(){
        final Set<Integer> set = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Integer>());
        //It's going to consist of 4 queries 
        List<String> queriesToConcurrentExecution = new ArrayList<String>();     
        //Obtaining the queries
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
        for(final String sql : queriesToConcurrentExecution){
            executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    List<Integer> l = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource).queryForList(sql, Integer.class);
                    set.addAll(l);
                }
            });
        }
        executor.shutdown();

        return set;
}
```

The thing is that implementation of `//Other methods` is the same in both cases. So I tend to wrap the `getPlayerRegisteredIds()` into some interface  and then provide two different implementation of it for the same Dao class thorugh its constructor. Is that correct?

In the [official `DAO`-pattern's description](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) said that the `DAO` acts like an adapter between a bussines object and `DataSource`, but in my case it uses an object that itself uses dataSource.

***QUESTION***: Should we always adhere to using the dataSource object *directly* in DAO? Is that the necessary requirement?

Comment: I would say you should adhere to **never** use a `DataSource` directly in a DAO. The DataSource is the source of a `Connection` and when your code executes multiple DAO calls, they should be part of the same transaction, so they have to share the same connection.

Comment: @Andreas What do you mean, multiple DAO calls? Calling methods from the diffefent DAOs in the same transaction?

Comment: The DAO implements your Data Access logic. Your *business logic* calls your DAO. If your business logic needs to create an Order and remove the Items from storage (reduce inventory count), that's two DAO calls, and they must happen together, so they must be in the same transaction, so they must share the same connection.

Comment: @Andreas Very interesting point, thank you. I've just never thought about that. So how should we wrap the dataSource object in order to prevent something bad happened because of two or more DAO-calls?

Comment: If you use a framework like Spring or EJB, they will handle it for you. If you do JDBC manually, the business logic has to define the transaction boundary, and will therefore have to obtain the connection from the DataSource, start the transaction (`setAutoCommit(false)`), pass the connection to the DAOs, then `commit()` upon successful return, or `rollback()` in case of error (exception), and finally `close()` the connection.

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I use spring. So, it's not bad if I wrap the implementaion of the method into a bean and then inject it, right?

Comment: @Andreas The OP uses JdbcTemplate which is transaction-aware. Multiple calls to JdbcTemplate will all get the same connection automatically if they're called in the same transaction.

Comment: @JBNizet You're right. Sorry, I got confused because we never stored the DataSource in our DAO classes, we created and stored the JDBCTemplate when the DataSource was injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see nothing fundamentally wrong in what you plan to use: the interface used by the DAO and containing that specific method is a *strategy*, and the DAO would delegate to one or the other strategy implementation.

The DAO still has its role of containing daa access methods, and it's free to implement them the way it wants to, even if that includes delegating to other components.